# Read chunked HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have a GET API request that returns a very large JSON.

Is there any way to read chunks of that JSON in java spring boot via restTemplate?

Comment: Assuming that we are talking about chunked encoding, this should be done out of the box transparently. Also check [ask]

Comment: You're using the word [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) wrong. JSON isn't very suitable as a response type if you want to read and process it in parts.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an JSON api for that. If you don't have a api for that you simply can't anything with your large JSON. You you can download a simple JSON api here: https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple .
There you can parse ur very large JSON into a JsonObject with
`final JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(ur big json string)`.
If you want to read chunks of the JSON you can use the `obj.get(key)` method.

Example:
Your JSON is: {test:"test1"}

`final JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse("{test:\"test1\"}");`

`obj.get("test");`
It will return test1.

If I made any misteak then correct me.

Edit: I understand it now. You could just remove parts of the Json by using obj.remove(key) and your json shouldn't be that big